# CSS/HTML : How to counter an overlay

Tags: html, css

I just want to ask something about overlays.

I have an overlayed div stretched full length,
but I want the center part of this div not to be overlayed. 
I don't know if this is possible or what but I want to know what can be the possible solutions.

my html set up:

```
<div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>       

<div>
```

my overlay code:

```
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6); /* overlay */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please explain more and try to provide a live example

Comment: i edit my question, what i mean about "ed" is overlayed.

Comment: you may have to create an inner div or a span and have another css for it..

Comment: If i understand right,  *NO* you can't do something like this, not with simple `html` or `css`, maybe canvas.

Comment: @SurajRao i already did that but what is the exact css code to counter an overlay?